# select case when number is distinct then 1 else 0

Tags: sql, oracle, distinct

I want to get the expected output such that when number happens first time in the account group, then display 1, otherwise if it happens another time, display null or 0. The same logic for other account groups.

The logic I can think is

```
select *,
case when number happens first time then 1 else null 
over (partition by account order by number) from table. 

account number  expected output
abc     20      1
abc     20      0
abc     30      1
def     20      1
def     30      1
def     30      0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use lag

```
  select *,case when number=lag(number) over(partition by account order by account)
           then 0 else 1 end as val
      from table_name
```

Answer (score 0):

You almost had it!

```
select account, number
case when Row_Number() OVER (partition by account order by number) = 1 THEN 1 END ExpOut
from table
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I figured it out

Answer (score 0):

@PaulX's answer is close, but the partitioning isn't quite right. You can do:

```
-- CTE for sample data
with your_table (account, num) as (
            select 'abc', 20 from dual
  union all select 'abc', 20 from dual
  union all select 'abc', 30 from dual
  union all select 'def', 20 from dual
  union all select 'def', 30 from dual
  union all select 'def', 30 from dual
)
select account, num,
  case when row_number() over (partition by account, num order by null) = 1
       then 1
       else 0
  end as output
from your_table;

ACCOUNT        NUM     OUTPUT
------- ---------- ----------
abc             20          1
abc             20          0
abc             30          1
def             20          1
def             30          1
def             30          0
```

(adjusted for legal column names; hopefully you don't actually have quoited identifiers...)

If you want nulls rather than zeros then just leave out the `else 0` part. And this just assumes by 'first' you mean the first returned in your result set, as otherwise - at least with the columns you showed - there is no obvious alternative. If you actually have other columns, particularly if you're using any others for the ordering of the result set, then you can apply the same ordering inside the `partition` clause to make it consistent.

Comment: Thank you Alex, I figured it out!